# Работа с датой в PHP и MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Задача: Сделать так чтобы каждый месяц 1 числа в БД записывалось какое-то значение.
Есть идеи как это реализовать?

Comment: Вариант с триггерами не подходит?

Comment: @Дмитрий А как вы себе это представляете? По-моему триггеры плохо подходят под эту задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте события

```
CREATE EVENT month_start ON SCHEDULE
  AT '2018-10-01' EVERY MONTH
DO
  INSERT INTO my_table (
    `date`
  ) VALUES (
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  );
```